# ArcHydro Error 000944 Output feature class cannot be in the in_memory workspace

Tags: arcgis-pro, arc-hydro

I am using I believe ArcHydro 2.9 in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.1. I was running Subwatershed Delineation in archydro and it gave the following error:

```
Processing 3056 point(s)...
Snapping points...
Processing 1 of 3056...
snapdist 0.0
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000944: Output feature class cannot be in the in_memory workspace.
Failed to execute (Project).

('line 222', 'c:\\program files\\arcgis\\pro\\Resources\\ArcToolbox\\Scripts\\ArcHydro\\snappoint.py', '')
Snap Point operation failed.
NOTOK
Finished at 2022-03-15 15:39:54
Failed script Subwatershed Delineation...
Failed to execute (SubwatershedDelineation).
```

I looked at the python source code, it is the following line:

```
#Need to project
raster_spref = arcpy.Describe(insnapraster).spatialReference
arcpy.management.Project(inpoint,outfcnosnap,raster_spref ) # <- line 222
```

in my project, all data are in file geodatabase and I already have default database file set for the project. I checked online and it appears many people have this same issue when running archydro.

Comment: As a test, could you try moving the input data out of the GDB? Do you get the same error then? Or possibly choosing an output location that is not a GDB?

Comment: I am not sure towards what ends would such tests accomplish?

Comment: Looking at the error it looks like the format isn’t supported as in memory storage. So changing the input and output to shapefile will eliminate the format as an issue with the tool. Just a thought, narrowing down the variables etc.